# Arena doesn't start the simulation but it's stuck on "running...."

Tags: simulation, arena-simulation

I have created a simulation model on the Arena Simulator, and now I would like to see its results to verify its significance. However, the simulation is not starting; the screen remains stuck in 'running' mode. What could be the possible causes? The properties of my computer are as follows:

Processore  AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics            2.10 GHz
RAM installata  8.00 GB (7.35 GB utilizzabile)
Tipo sistema    Sistema operativo a 64 bit, processore basato su x64

I've checked if there are errors in the model but there aren't,I really don't know what to do because it's the first time I use this software for university reasons.